# How to use logical operator Or in Jasmine?

Tags: testing, jasmine

I need to say the test was successful if one of the two expectations is met:
I used the code below, but that's not working

```js
   expect(colorGenerator(testArray ,testMin, testMax)).toEqual("green" || "red")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
const colors = ['green', 'red'];
const isEitherGreenOrRed = colors.some(color => colorGenerator(testArray ,testMin, testMax) === color);
expect(isEitherGreenOrRed).toBeTrue();
```

We assign `green` and `red` inside of an array and then we check that it is one of the entries with the array `some`.

Answer (score 0):

You can match with a regex

```js
expect(colorGenerator(testArray ,testMin, testMax)).toMatch(/red|green/)
```